# Why does this bubble sorting algorithm work in Javascript but not in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

In Javascript, you can get away with array sorters like these

```
function sorter(array) {
  var done = false
  while (!done) {
    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      done = true;
      if (array[i-1] > array[i]) {
        done = false;
        var tmp = array[i-1];
        array[i-1] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}

var index = [3, 8, 2, 4, 213, 5, 23, 75,23, 43];
sorter(index);
console.log(index);
```

When I wanted to convert this code to python, I surprisingly got an infinite loop of calculating, it might be because I'm not very familiar with python.

```
def sorter(array):
    done = False
    while (done == False):
        for i in range(len(array)):
            done = True
            if array[i-1] > array[i]:
                done = False
                tmp = array[i-1]
                array[i-1] = array[i]
                array[i] = tmp
    return array


index = [2, 35, 6, 4, 8, 7]
sorter(index)
print(index)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem is that you don't know Python *quite* well enough.  Your loop limits are wrong:

```
    for i in range(len(array)):
```

On the first iteration of this loop, i=0, so i-1 is -1.

array[-1] is the *last* element of the list.  Thus, every time you start again, you swap the last element of the list with the first, and have to bubble it back to the end, never finishing.

Any simple tracing of your program would have shown you the effect.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

---

**REPAIR**

```
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
```

Comment: The Javascript code also contains this error, so this fixes the issue but doesn't quite explain the problem in full.

Comment: Thank you, no hard feelings we're all just learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

```
def sorter(array):
    a = array.sort()
    return a


index = [2, 35, 6, 4, 8, 7]
sorter(index)
print(index)
```

Comment: I knew that this existed. However, I wanted to try to use an algorithm without this function.